# multiple moving averages in mysql

Tags: mysql, moving-average

I have to calculate moving averages (with different periods) on my dataset in mysql. I have tried 2 ways to calculate the averages but both are taking considerable amount of time. Sharing the code below.

**Method:-1**

```
select t1.*, 
    (select avg(t2.last_price) 
        from temp_data t2 
        where t2.rownum>t1.rownum-50 and t2.rownum<=t1.rownum and t1.script_code=t2.script_code) as 'ma_small_price'
from temp_data t1;
```

**Method:-2**

```
select t1.*, avg(t2.last_price) 'ma_small_price'
from temp_data t1
join temp_data t2
where t2.rownum>t1.rownum-50 and t2.rownum<=t1.rownum and t1.script_code=t2.script_code
group by t1.id,t1.date, t1.time;
```

**This is the table structure:**

```
  CREATE TABLE `temp_data` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `rownum` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `script_code` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `time` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_price` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_qty` float DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

rownum is a column with consecutive row numbers. ID was the primary key but wasn't consecutive so I had to add a separate column

Link for the sample data:https://www.dropbox.com/s/z8iacqvlkjdx6ax/temp_data_sample.xlsx?dl=0

Next I have to calculate multiple moving averages on the same data **parallely** but the periods (specified as 50 in the code above) are different.

My data set is huge and growing (> 1 mil rows) and the time it takes for these queries to run is significant - ~20 mins each. Seeking inputs on how these queries can be improved to reduce the run time. Thanks!!

Comment: This looks a lot like Oracle code.  Are you sure that you are using MySQL?

Comment: yes, I am sure...using them in mysql server which is also hosted on my machine

Comment: Please post some table structure and sample data.  It would seem that `rownum` is actually a column name.

Comment: I have added the table structure. rownum is a column with consecutive row numbers. ID was the primary key but wasn't consecutive so I had to add a separate column. Not sure how to add sample attachment for the data. how can I attach it here?

Comment: You have no indexes. This, above all, is what's killing performance.

Comment: thanks, I am adding indexes and will try again. How should I best address the multiple moving averages concern. I am afraid that by creating multiple parallel sub queries will also multiply the execution time...

Comment: To answer that, post up sample data and a desired result, as per TB's suggestion. I suggest you use a smaller range for the sample, e.g. a 3 row moving average acting on 12 rows of data.

Comment: I have converted rownum to PK and added index for script_code. This reduced the execution time from total (run+fetching 1000 rows) 250 secs to 32 secs. Data in the query was approx. 0.12 mill records Thanks all for your help. I will try the solution given by @Guy L

Comment: dropbox link for the data: https://www.dropbox.com/s/z8iacqvlkjdx6ax/temp_data_sample.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: I don't see what's to be gained from downloading your whole data set. As I mentioned, a sample set of 12 rows is usually enough.

Comment: sorry the reason for sharing the bigger dataset was only to give perspective about the data and if the testing on it can help in optimizing run time...thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question
The challenge is to group by the iterations each line with a jump
So we need to define a start period and an end period and join the same table between these periods

I added order by and limit because of the size of the table

I would also add indexes to the rownum column, to have the join and the group run faster

hope that helps

```
ALTER TABLE temp_data ADD key rownum (rownum) ;


    SELECT 
         t3.rownum AS endp, 
        AVG(t3.last_price)
        FROM
temp_data t3
INNER JOIN temp_data t ON t.rownum BETWEEN  MAX(IFNULL(t3.rownum, 0)) - 50 AND t3.endp
        GROUP BY
        endp
ORDER BY rownum DESC
LIMIT 0,1000
```

Comment: Are you sure that this is faster?

Comment: I need to loose the sub query and add a proper limit... I also wanted to expand my answer regarding indexes

Comment: It would also be nice to get rid of the redundant rownum column

Comment: frankly, copying the whole thing into a new table with rownum as the primary key would be a lot faster than any of this, but the worst thing is the unlimited join in the initial query... this should be faster, if date is indexed, but it may create artifacts or inconsistencies by chunking the data into date periods.

Comment: that's why I edited my answer an adding the index issue as well

Comment: This works great. Got your point of joining the part of the data set only. This has reduced the run time considerably. Thanks!!

Comment: happy to hear :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay. First of all, with only 1M rows this should not take 20 minutes. More like 20 seconds. If your rownum column is unique, it should be indexed as a unique key. It should also be an unsigned int. Doing those things will cut your query time a lot, because it seems that right now you are doing a full unsorted table scan for each and every join.

Secondly, unless there is some reason that is not obvious for a database that's comparing a lot of historical data, you should be using an ISAM table, not InnoDB.

Thirdly, script_code must be indexed or else you will be doing a full table scan.

More:
* Your join statement in method-2 is joining every single row to every row and then performing the where. You should LEFT JOIN ON rownum>t1.rownum-50 AND rownum<=t1.rownum, instead of doing a general join and then running the where. That would significantly speed up the query even without indexing rownum.
* If you expect a lot more data, you should also look into partitioning your table based on rownum. Partitions can be excellent for speeding up these sorts of reads where most of the data you're accessing is sequential and will fall within one or two of the partitions. In your case, you could also partition by date which might be handy for other operations.
* Look at EXPLAIN SELECT and see what keys are being used on the joins. Consider a USE INDEX hint to use rownum instead of the primary key for the join.

It doesn't appear that either of your queries is incorrect, per se. Once you have done the above optimizations, my guess is that your method-1 (subquery) will still be faster than a correct JOIN ON without the WHERE in method-2.

At that point, you should use EXPLAIN SELECT to see what is being done in each query. It will show you how many rows are being read and joined, and which indices are being used, helping you narrow down any issues with un-indexed joins.

Comment: A decade ago, there may have been some truth in the old saw about MyISAM vs InnoDB, but not any longer. Besides, referential integrity trumps any (tiny, and I suspect, non-existent) potential performance benefits

Comment: Full disclosure, I used to do almost everything with InnoDB ten years ago. Really just a lot of corner cases concerning locks on large tables that would crash large databases convinced me it was better to go with total brief write locks and MyISAM than row level locking. My gut feeling after all these years is that large joins are faster with MyISAM, but then again that's coming from an environment where there are almost always some writes trying to happen at the same time, so maybe the speed difference in a read-only environment is negligible. The thing is, if you don't need it, why use it?